# Block text fields if others contain text?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, input

is there a way (preferrably with jQuery) to block text inputs if others contain text?

I can see ways to block input fields all the time, but not dynamically as others contain text.

```
<input name="inputone" id="i_one" type="text" value="">
<input name="inputtwo" id="i_two" type="text" value="">
<input name="inputthree" id="i_three" type="text" value="">
```

It's a real simple set-up. I just need if "i_one" contains any text, block "i_two" and "i_three" from receiving any input. but if user deletes what they've typed in "i_one" before submitting the form, the block will be lifted so user can use a different field instead.

Comment: +1 because I have no idea why you got a down vote.

Comment: Thanks - I thought it was a valid question :/ bahaha :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this look?

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
  $(this).siblings().prop('disabled', this.value.length ? true : false)
});
```

Of course, you might want to tweak it to not act on *all* input elements, by adding a special class to the elements you want to listen to.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eW6mr/) if you want to tweak/play with it.

Comment: Use `this.value` over `$(this).val()` - you've just saved yourself two unnecessary function calls. Just because jQuery provides a way to access something that doesn't mean it's **always** appropriate to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this pretty quickly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").on("input", function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $("input").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else {
            $("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```